# Inheritance and cast

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, casting, parent-child

I'm having some trouble with the class casting in C++.
To learn, I wanted to create a class which just make operations, like sums, but it seems to crash everytime I launch it.

Here is my simple classes:

```
#include <iostream>


class CCalculation {
public:
CCalculation() {};
virtual int calculate() = 0;
};


class CCalc_CONST : public CCalculation {
    int x;
public:
    CCalc_CONST(int a) : x(a) {};
    int calculate() { return x; };
};    


class CCalc_ADD : public CCalculation {
    CCalculation *x;
    CCalculation *y;
public:
    CCalc_ADD(CCalculation *a, CCalculation *b) {
        this->x = a;
        this->y = b;
    };
    int calculate() {
        std::cout << "Calculation...\n";
        return x->calculate() + y->calculate();
    };
};
```

And my test:

```
    CCalculation *a = &CCalc_CONST(4);
    CCalculation *b = &CCalc_CONST(1);
    CCalculation *c = &CCalc_ADD(a,b);

    std::cout << "res: " << c->calculate() << "\n";
```

It seems to crash everytime (I got no compiler error or warning).
The only way to run it I found is when I'm printing a->calculate and b->calculate at the CCalc_ADD construction. I have absolutely no clue why i need to call the calculate function to make it work.

Can someone please explains to me how to actually do it ?

Comment: It would work better with a lot less pointers. And the compiler should warn you about taking the address of temporaries. They won't stay around long enough for you to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using new.  Test like this:

```
CCalculation *a = new CCalc_CONST(4);
CCalculation *b = new CCalc_CONST(1);
CCalculation *c = new CCalc_ADD(a,b);
```

You can weed out things like address-of on temporaries by compiling with `-Wall`, which enables all compiler warnings.  The compiler is your friend and is there to help. Love the compiler.

Comment: The solution is so simple I'm a little bit sad. Thank you so much, will try -Wall next time.

Comment: You read a book one page at a time, not by stuffing the whole thing down your throat at once.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should turn on all warnings (see docs to your compiler, in  `gcc` `-Wall`)

Then you will see, that your compiler will blame you:

```
1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
1.cpp:56:37: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
1.cpp:57:37: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
1.cpp:58:37: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

Actually, here

```
CCalculation *a = &CCalc_CONST(4);
```

you just create temporary object that will be destroyed imminently after creation and you get broken pointer.

You have 2 alternatives:

1. create objects in dynamic memory (but in this case I will recommend make complex calculation owner of simpler)

   ```
   class CCalc_ADD : public CCalculation {
       std::unique_ptr<CCalculation> x;
       std::unique_ptr<CCalculation> y;
   public:
       CCalc_ADD(CCalculation *a, CCalculation *b):x(a), y(b)
       {
       };
       int calculate() {
           std::cout << "Calculation...\n";
           return x->calculate() + y->calculate();
       };
   };


   std::unique_ptr<CCalculation> a(new CCalc_CONST(4));
   //... 
   CCalc_ADD c (std::move(a), std::move(b));
   ```
2. replace pointers with references. Then you can use value semantics.

Answer (score 2):

To get a working program you don't even need to use `new`:

```
CCalc_CONST a(4);
CCalc_CONST b(1);
CCalc_ADD   c(&a,&b);

std::cout << "res: " << c.calculate() << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access temporary objects that are no longer alive. Use operator `new` for allocating memory for an object and calling its constructor.

```
CCalculation *a = new CCalc_CONST(4);
CCalculation *b = new CCalc_CONST(1);
CCalculation *c = new CCalc_ADD(a,b);
```

I have tried it with GCC and it issues a very clear warning about this:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:35:33: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:36:37: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:37:37: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```